# Grails Dispatch error

Tags: java, grails

We are becoming insane with this issue, we get too many dispatch errors , in random places of the system, we give a clean, upgrade and build to generate the war, in a clean environment, we use grails 1.3.5 with java 1.6, we get this:

Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: null
Servlet: grails
URI: /data/Data/findData.dispatch
Exception Message: 
Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView: null 
Class: /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/error.gsp 
At Line: [-1] 
Code Snippet:

we were told it was for our Java VM, We use:

-server -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xss1m -Xmn10000m -Xms12000m -Xmx32768m -XX:PermSize=384M -XX:MaxPermSize=384M

we have a server with 32 GB of ram, it runs just this war in tomcat.

any idea?, we would appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

We fixed it, by installing Tomcat 6.35 in linux, we stopped using tomcat without the installer.